# PostgreSQL - partial dump of large objects (pg_largeobject table)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, dump, pg-dump, scripting

**Context** : Our web-app is like a collaboration platform where you can share files, appointments, survey and so on. An instance of this web-app is divided in communities, each one is independent to each other but share the same PostgreSQL database.

**Target** : actually what i'm trying to do is to write a shell script in order to make regular backups of communities separately. This means that I need to select  only part of the data inside the various Postgre tables and export/dump the community data.

**Obstacle** : 
My big problem is with the pg_largeobjects table, used to store the BLOB of files. This table use OIDs as pk (something I don't relly like by the way). The table **files** (containing files metadata) , has a reference to the pg_largeobject OID.

**Solutions considered** :

1. - Select all the OIDs from files table WHERE community_id = something.
   - And afterwards, I could export the data stream from pg_largeobjects using `[lo_export][1]` function giving all the OIDs selected in the previous operation:

> int lo_export(PGconn *conn, Oid lobjId, const char *filename);
>   
>   
>   The problem with this approach is when i will try to restore pg_largeobject records, I need to keep the same OIDs or the relation will be broken. I can use the function `lo_import_with_oid` that permit to define the desired OID, but in most cases OIDs will be already occupied from the original data, and for this reason the import will generate a new OID, that will not satisfact the relation with the rest of the database.

2. I still don't know how I could achieve this, but i try to explain:

   - during the export I could select and save all the PK of the files table record of the certain community (let's call it filesPKs).
   - I will then perform a `[lo_export]` of pg_largeobjects
   - and during the `lo_import` I could ignore the fact that new OID are being generated. But in someway i would save the list of these new OIDs inserted.
   - as final step I could update all the rows(using filesPKs reference) in the files table in order to make them point to the new imported pg_largeobject records.

This second procedure in my opinion is very difficult, because I still don't see how could I update files rows in order to point to the correct largeobject.

- An other option, that fancifully would be the best one, would be to modify the pg_largeobject table in order to have an additional column with a (static) reference to files table. But after a test it seems to be impossible:

> testdb=# alter table pg_largeobject add column prova text;  ERROR: 
>   permission denied: "pg_largeobject" is a system catalog
>   
>   **Questions** :

- Any one else faced this issue?
- Am I just missing something, or taking the wrong approach?
- Out there exist an other way to export/dump pg_largeobjects records, exporting all the fields, not only the data stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue as follow (2nd considered solution - revisited):

All in a while cicle, for every file:

- select file_id , file_version, oid and put them in 3 variables
- perform a [lo_export] of pg_largeobjects that require oid a path+filename to be defined. The filename will be the concatenation of the file_id and file_version.
- during lo_import new OID will be generated. But using the filename defined above, I can perform the last step:
- update all the rows in the files table in order to make them point to the new imported pg_largeobject records and mantain the relation consistecy